# Continuity of $T:R^R\to R^R$ such that $f(x)\mapsto[f(x)]^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$T$ is a map from the almost metric* space $(\mathbb R^\mathbb R,d_\infty)$  into itself such that each function is mapped to the square of itself.

If we assume that it is continous, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, then we have some $\delta$ such that $d_\infty(f,g)<\delta\implies d_\infty(T(f),T(g))<\epsilon$ but if we pick $f(x)=x, $ and $g(x)=x+k,k<\delta$ but then $x,d_\infty(T(f),T(g))=\infty$

I think where I am confused is, does $d_\infty$ make it so that we need uniformly continuous function $T:\mathbb R^\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^\mathbb R$ for $T:(\mathbb R^\mathbb R,d_\infty)\to(\mathbb R^\mathbb R,d_\infty)$ to be continous?

edit: $$d_\infty(f,g)=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|\forall x \in \mathbb R\}$$
edit: *almost metric space

Comment: Your metric space is not a metric space unless you mean $\{f\in \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} | d_{\infty}(f)<\infty\}$.

Comment: It might not technically be a metric space, but it's very close to being one.  And it's even metrizable by $\frac{d_\infty}{d_\infty+1}$ (where of course we take this to be 1 if $d_\infty(f, g) = \infty$).

Comment: But if we allow unbounded functions, then $T$ is not continuous since for $f(x) = x$, $d_\infty(f, f + \epsilon) = \infty$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, sorry the way I stated my titles sounds like"prove that this is continuous" I should I have said "Prove or disprove this is continuous"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your space is $\{f\in \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} | d_{\infty}(f)<\infty\}$, then:

$$|f^2(x)-g^2(x)|=|f(x)-g(x)||f(x)+g(x)|\le M |f(x)-g(x)|$$

So if $\operatorname{essup}_{x\in \Bbb{R}} |f(x)-g(x)|\lt \delta=\varepsilon/M$ then...

Comment: This is not the space